# Dreamweaver CS5 Dynamic File Discovery Mode - does it work with a remote server?

Tags: dreamweaver, flash-cs5

Ok, I cannot find the answer to this question anywhere. Does this new feature just not work with a remote server? I do not have a local server setup, just because I typically work remotely so I don't have to always set up two environments every time I start a new project (remote always has to be there no matter what so the client can see it (unless, can a local server be setup with a service like dynamicDNS for others to see a site remotely?).

This feature works when I am using something as simple has PHP includes for a template system, but if I attempt it with something like a wordpress install, I always get the error "Dynamically-related files could not be resolved because the site definition is not correct for this server"

Answer (score 3):

I personally installed wordpress severals times locally as i could only make the dynamic discover feature work maybe once or twice each time i installed, then I would get this error. After trying several different server setups i almost gave up. Today I was working with wordpress outside of dreamweaver and was looking for a way to change permalinks to have a php extension. After looking for a while Inoticed people kept talking about making differnet servers like xamp able to handle permalinks. Then the light came on for me and I realized each time I installed wordpress I would eventually change the default permalink to day and name. So I turned it back to default in wordpress and bingo I could now discover the files. Tried this several times to make sure this was the issue. Yippe!! Could be your issue...or not

Michael